# Submit form on dropdown change using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following which calls another file and spits output based on the dropdown value. It works fine except I can't seem to get it to work correctly without a submit button. This works except it will redirect itself to `process.php` with the correct output. The whole point of this code is to display the output within the empty div (`output`).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dropdown').change( function() {
       $('#myform').submit();
       $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
           data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
           type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
           url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
           success: function(response) { // on success..
               $('#output').html(response); // update the DIV
           }
       });
       return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });
});


<form id="myform" method=POST action="process.php">
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="QU">QU</option>
    <option value="QF">QF</option>
    <option value="QC">QC</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Do you need to submit the form in the code above if you are using ajax to get the information from process.php?

Comment: A return false in the change event won't prevent the form from submitting, and you're submitting it everytime the select changes, reloading the page, so it won't really work at all ?

Comment: Good question, i grabbed it code from somewhere else. Basically I want to pull data from mysql and display it inside the `output` div. It works fine but, if there's a better way, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the JQuery load function can do what you are after in less code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dropdown').change( function() {

    $('#output').load('/process.php',{dropdown: $(this).val()});

    });
});


<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="QU">QU</option>
    <option value="QF">QF</option>
    <option value="QC">QC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Woah, this works and much less code. So is this any different from the code above?

Comment: First of all in your above code you never needed the form. Since we are using ajax. Apart from that load just combines the replace and the ajax call in one. It is less flexible but less code. If you need something special use ajax and do your own replace. If not use load it's quicker.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use ajax then don't submit the form, also in the dropdown change event `this` is the dropdown element not the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dropdown').change( function() {
       $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
           data: $('#myform').serialize(), // serialize the form
           type: $('#myform').attr('method'), // GET or POST from the form
           url: $('#myform').attr('action'), // the file to call from the form
           success: function(response) { // on success..
               $('#output').html(response); // update the DIV
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

What this is doing:

1. On change of dropdown
2. using ajax so we have to prevent the default behavior of form submission with `prevDef()`
3. Then your ajax call which `submits the value` and `process it to process.php` and the output `response on process.php gets loaded` in the `#output div`

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dropdown').change( function() {
          $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
              data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
              type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
              url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
              success: function(response) { // on success..
                  $('#output').html(response); // update the DIV
              }
          });
       });
   });
   ```